# How to save validated third party API data if form validation fails

Tags: forms

Here's my issue.  During user register I'm adding fields via form_alter and creating a [stripe](http://stripe.com) account.  When validation fails $form_state gets wiped out and when the user passes through validation again a second account gets created.

I'm thinking about using cache_set to hang on to the account info until the user gets through the registration process error free but is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like before your `mymodule_form_validation($form, &$form_state)` function returns you want to store the Stripe information in the users `$_SESSION` array as a valid attempt/data.

You write to user session using the global session value in PHP and Drupal adds it to the Users' DB/Mongo user session info at the end of page execution. For example:

```
// in your form validation code ...
$_SESSION['stripe_username'] = 'john_doe';
```

On form load simply prepopulate the form data from $_SESSION. Eg, you're stuffing the content into session because it will be wiped on form reload -- then you're replacing it so a 2nd account isnt created.

Comment: I thought about using sessions for this but I don't know how sensitive the customer id is to stripe (really the only thing I want to persist).

Comment: Reading up on sessions again and this may be the easiest way to go and it's not nearly as insecure as I thought it might be.

Answer (score 0):

Another option for this particular use case may be

- [form_set_value](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!form.inc/function/form_set_value/7)

To set the form value during validation.

> Use this function to change the submitted value of a form element in a
>   form validation function, so that the changed value persists in
>   $form_state through the remaining validation and submission handlers.

For example, on validation error, you could store the stripe ID in a `'#type' => 'value'` form element and thereby make it available for the subsequent request.

Comment: It won't work. FAPI will only persist things with a #default_value.  So hidden elements and the $form_state['values'] array get blown away when the form is rebuilt after failed validation. You can do some trickery with $form_state['rebuild'] = true but I would prefer to keep this as straightforward as possible. The key here is the last part of the sentence - _through the remaining validation and submission handlers._. See [form_builder](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21form.inc/function/form_builder/7).